# What does this Rx glyph mean in what looks like Latin?

Tags: literature, writing

What does this glyph (red) mean? Also, what usage was there for it and the other glyph that looks like a colon (blue)?

[image]

Comment: Rx= Rum.  Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation for the handwriting conventions reenacted in this bit of printing.  The wiggle sign over the "a" at the end of the line with your red mark is a missing "m" in "theologiam".  The : is (I think) a punctuation mark.

Comment: Look at the bottom of what Google books calls page 54 of https://books.google.com/books?id=PxpSAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=satyri+veneream+omnem++terrestris+virtus+perficitur&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTz7i247PaAhVEMd8KHV0XC4oQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=satyri%20veneream%20omnem%20%20terrestris%20virtus%20perficitur&f=false

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking at a [scribal abbreviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation) for "-rum".  That is, the word is actually [*philosophorum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/philosophorum), but with the last three letters replaced with [ꝶ](http://graphemica.com/%EA%9D%B6). Here is a screenshot of the enlarged character from the graphemica page:

[image]

The colon is probably a *punctus elevatus* which is sometimes written without its tail, i.e. like a colon. It's basically like our modern comma.

Comment: just found out that not many fonts have this glyph, even premium ones like Garamond Premier Pro are missing it. Such a shame.